# Spring @KafkaListener execute and poll records after certain interval

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

We wanted to consume the records after a certain interval (e.g. every 5 minutes).
Consumer properties are standard:

```
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(300000);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.BATCH);
    return factory;
}
```

Even though when i change the property `setPollTimeout` it doesnot poll after defined interval (5 minutes), it continuously polls after 30 seconds, here are my logs:

```
2018-01-23 18:07:26.875 INFO 60905 --- [        2-0-C-1] c.t.k.s.consumer.FavoriteEventConsumer   : Consumed: san@1516710960000->1516711080000 2

2018-01-23 18:07:56.901 INFO 60905 --- [        2-0-C-1] c.t.k.s.consumer.FavoriteEventConsumer   : Consumed: san@1516710960000->1516711080000 4
```

We were trying to build a kafka stream application with windowed aggregations and planning to consume the window x after y interval.

I can see that in the class: `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`, `setConsumerTaskExecutor` is set:

```
if (containerProperties.getConsumerTaskExecutor() == null) {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor consumerExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(
                (getBeanName() == null ? "" : getBeanName()) + "-C-");
        containerProperties.setConsumerTaskExecutor(consumerExecutor);
    }
```

But how do we configure when this (frequency) thread pool polls records. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot control the rate at which the consumer polls, the pollTimeout is how long the `poll()` will wait for new records to arrive. If new records arrive more often, it will not wait that long.

If you wish to control the rate at which you receive records, simply use the `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` to create a consumer and poll it whenever you want.

You can't use that with a `@KafkaListener` though - you have to deal with the record yourself.

Comment: Why do you think that this is not configurable?

Comment: You can somewhat control it with min.fetch.bytes and max.fetch.wait.ms. but it is not precise. Next release 2.3 adds an idle between polls property to help with this.

Comment: It should be noted that `min.fetch.bytes` needs to be set to more than 1 in order for `max.fetch.wait.ms` to take effect. Found that info https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/827#issuecomment-430396628

Answer (score 6):

This feature was introduced in 2.3 version.

> Starting with version 2.3, the ContainerProperties provides an
> **idleBetweenPolls** option to let the main loop in the listener container
> to sleep between KafkaConsumer.poll() calls. An actual sleep interval
> is selected as the minimum from the provided option and difference
> between the max.poll.interval.ms consumer config and the current
> records batch processing time.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/

KafkaListenerConfig.java

```
package br.com.sicredi.spi.icom.consumer.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaListenerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(100); // 100 miliseconds
        
        return factory;
    }

    private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        // ... 
        return props;
    }
}
```

Comment: The same question. It's not working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control rate at which Kafka consumer using Spring @KafkaListener, please autowire KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry bean use in following way and access the required MessageListenerContainer. thereafter, you can use the pause() and resume() functionalities to control the required behaviour.

```
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry listener;

@Autowired
private Map<String, Set<String>> getTopicListenerMap(){
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(listener.getListenerContainerIds());
    Map<String, Set<String>> topicListenerMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(String topic: topics){
        topicListenerMap.put(topic, new HashSet<>());
    }
    for(String key: ids){
        for (String topic : listener.getListenerContainer(key).getContainerProperties().getTopics()){
            topicListenerMap.get(topic).add(key);
        }
    }
    return topicListenerMap;
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "topic", containerFactory = "smsListener")
public void listenWithHeaders(@Payload List<String> messageList, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitionList,
                              @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Integer> offsetList) {
    try{
        LOG.info("Received message count: "+(messageList!=null ? messageList.size(): 0)+", offset start: "+offsetList.get(0)+", end: "+offsetList.get(offsetList.size()-1));
        pauseIfRequired(topic);
        for(int i=0; i<messageList.size(); i++){
            // process the messages
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error("", e);
    }finally {
        resumeIfPaused(topic);
    }
}

private void pauseIfRequired(String topic){
    try{ 
        boolean flag = pausingCondition;
        if(flag){
            LOG.info("pausing topic: "+topic);
            for(String listenerKey: getTopicListenerMap().get(topic)){
                listener.getListenerContainer(listenerKey).pause();
            }
            LOG.info("topic paused: "+topic);
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error("", e);
    }
}

private void resumeIfPaused(String topic){
    try {
        for (String listenerKey : getTopicListenerMap().get(topic)) {
            LOG.info("topic: "+topic+", containerPauseRequested: "+listener.getListenerContainer(listenerKey).isPauseRequested());
            if (listener.getListenerContainer(listenerKey).isPauseRequested()) {
                LOG.info("waiting to resume topic: " + topic + ", listener key: " + listenerKey);
                // wait while the condition to resume is fulfilled
                LOG.info("resuming topic: " + topic + ", listener key: " + listenerKey);
                listener.getListenerContainer(listenerKey).resume();
                LOG.info("topic resumed: " + topic + ", listener key: " + listenerKey);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error("", e);
    }
}
```