# Relational DB and kafka consumer sync

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a unique requirement where i have to fetch messages from a topic and persist it on db and then poll it by 15 minutes interval. Please could somebody suggest how to do it effectively using `Spring-Kafka` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement correctly you pretty much describe the solution - call poll every 15 minutes using a scheduled job (if you have a cluster of consumers then in order to retrieve all messages every 15 minutes use a Cron based schedule so they all poll at the same time, if it's just a single consumer you can just use a simple schedule to run every 15 minutes).

Each time you poll, persist the data from the records in your DB and commit the DB transaction. Use auto commit in Kafka with `commit.interval.ms` less than 15 minutes - that means each time you poll, the previous batch of records (which have definitely been persisted in the DB) will be committed in Kafka (note that auto-commit causes commit of offsets to happen synchronously in the poll method).

The other important configuration to set is `max.poll.interval.ms` - make that greater than 15 minutes otherwise a rebalance would get triggered between polls.

Note that if a rebalance does occur (as is generally inevitable at some point) you will consume the same records again. Simplest approach here is to use a unique index in the database and just catch and ignore the exception if you try to store the same record.

I would be interested in why you have the 15 minute requirement - the simplest way of consuming is just to poll continuously in a loop, or using a framework like spring-kafka, which again polls frequently. If you are just persisting the data from the records wouldn't it just work regardless of the interval between batches of records? I guess you have some other constraint to deal with (or I have just misunderstood your requirements)

Note, as mentioned in my comments below if you want to use spring-kafka there is an idle between polls property - https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html#setIdleBetweenPolls-long-

The other info above is still important if you take this approach rather than scheduling your own polling.

Comment: Oh hang on, I just spotted the need to use spring-kafka. Not sure if you.can force a 15 minute interval there. I'll check but you may have to just create your own instance of KafkaConsumer and poll in a @Scheduled method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410407/2568649 check this link, and especially the second comment, there is an idle between polls property now I think

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html#setIdleBetweenPolls-long- here we are

Comment: Thank you Chris. By the way poll has to be done from the database and then send it to another topic. Let me re-phrase
1. Consumer reads it from Topic-1
2. Stores it on DB
3. Poll it after 15 minutes
4. Store the message in topic T-2

Comment: Oh that's easier then, consume normally from topic 1 and store in DB, with some flag to say it's not yet published, then a scheduled job every 15 mins to select all that have that flag set, for each row, publish to topic 2 (make sure you have acks=all) and in the success callback from publishing, update the flag in the DB for that individual record). That way any publish failures just get retried on next scheduled execution. Only risk is if publishing took longer than 15 mins you'd process the same records twice, but you should handle duplicates in topic 2 consumers anyway.....

Comment: ... due to at least once semantics - a message could get published twice or consumed twice unless you enforce exactly once semantics but there's a performance cost to that so easier to accept duplicates and just handle them.

Comment: Acks all is important to avoid lost messages. Alternative approach to ensure you have published messages before updating the flag is to select every 15 mins as before, do nothing in success callback, but run a consumer on topic 2 (with a different group id to the intended consumer) and for each consumed record update the DB row. Then you definitely know the message has been published but there's a higher risk of not updating the flag for all rows within 15 mins

Comment: Sure Chris. Thanks again. I will try it out in couple of days and let you know. BTW what is your opinion about `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager`. In my limited knowledge it is  best suitable on a producer rather a consumer.

Comment: I haven't used Kafka transactions as I haven't really needed to, but it's on my list of things to read up on. My understanding is that a producer can publish messages but they are not visible to transaction aware consumers until committed. Whether that is useful may depend in whether you can involve that transaction in a 2 phase commit which has always been the problem with Kafka and RDBMS. Without transactions, at least once semantics means you can err on the side of duplicating messages, which is simple but I'll check out if tx would make life easier