# KafkaListener works infinitely

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I run an endpoint and send a message to topic `X`, Then on the cosumer side, doing some process and if the process fails, sending to `X.error` topic. When I cosume topic `X`, it's infinitely do some process.

1. `Kafka version: 3.1.2`
2. `Spring Boot version: 2.7.7`

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "X", groupId = "X-consumer", properties = "max.poll.interval.ms:1000")
    public void listenX(KafkaMessageDTO msg) {
    // some line of code here
    kafkaTokenMessageService.sendMessage("X.error", msg);
    }
```

I have write `properties = "max.poll.interval.ms:1000"` for listen to this topic for each second

Then I am sending the message to `X.error` topic but the problem as I mentioned before, `listenX` method infinitely works. What might be the problem?

Note: In `listenX` method I am just doing some CRUD process. Nothing else.
My `@KafkaListener` annotation from `org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener`

I have checked [KafkaListener](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.2.RELEASE/index.html?org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html) but I havent seen any parameter with `properties`. Still I am not sure if it's the problem because I have no error or warning on logs

Comment: What makes you think `max.poll.interval.ms:1000` does what it does? It should be a value expression, wrap it in `${}`. Like `${max.poll.interval.ms:1000}` so Spring will parse it. Although I'm not sure if those properties are actually passed through the properties resolution mechanism. What also helps is reading the current [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html) instead of some outdated version (you are reading the 2.2 docs whilst using 3.1).

Comment: To be honest, I can't see the any problem on my code and I am not controlled about `properties` option. Therefore, I said the problem might be on it. Thanks for updated docs @M.Deinum

Comment: It was my assumption (never assume I know) that you wanted to replace a dynamic value and generally properties are separated with `=` not a `:`. I also think the parser for the properties uses an `=`. That being said to control the polling interval you will need to configure the listener container. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402355/spring-kafkalistener-execute-and-poll-records-after-certain-interval

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. The `@KafkaListener` is fully based on the `KafkaConsumer` which is an event-driven forever subscriber. So, if record is available in the topic, it is delivered to this subscriber. What you try to achieve, please?

Comment: @ArtemBilan evertyhing works but the problem it works unnecessarily. When I send message to the topic, I want it works only once. Not infinitely. I am calling a topic only one and it runs infinitely. That's my problem

Answer (score 0):

If your goal to read from the Kafka topi only once, then you'd better to look into a API which does that on demand: `KafkaTemplate.receive(Collection<TopicPartitionOffset> requested, Duration pollTimeout)`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/template-receive.html